# jQuery find elements without data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

How can I find all elements without a certain data-attribute?

I've tried:

```
$list.find('li:not([data-stuff])');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: what is `$list` element, can you share the html as well

Comment: is the data attribute modified by script or is it present in the html markup

Comment: data is added by script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery stores `data` attributes in its cache, so you need to use filter:

```
var $li = $list.filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('stuff') != undefined;
});
// do something with $li...
```

Comment: you may have to check whether `data('suff')!=undefined` else falsy values like `false` and `0` will fail

Comment: @Vic If there was a selector to do exactly what you wanted, it would probably just do something similar to this internally anyway. But you could use something like [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/a-better-data-selector-for-jquery/) if you really wanted to do it in a selector. Hell, even build your own :)

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
$list.find('li').not('li[data-stuff]').addClass('foo');
```

The `addClass()` is just there as a placeholder.

Comment: Notice in that codepen how it only logs text for the two items that don't have a [data-stuff] attr. I assume you're looping through items or something in your code...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when you add the data via javascript instead of html. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doyfj